# MVC5 Google+ Authentication works on Local IIS Express but not on my Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, google-plus

I am using Google+ to control login to my MVC5 app. I have my startup.auth configured OK and using local IIS Express everything is great. I get the Google+ button on my Account page and clicking that takes me straight to the Google sign in page and then back to my application once the challenge is passed.

When I put my site up on to my 2012 server with IIS8, things fall apart! The button exists, but clicking it results in nothing.. I can see that the page is attempting to load something, but it sits there until I guess it times out. I never get to the Google login.

I have checked that anonymous authentication is enabled in IIS and no other authentication methods are enforced.

As a secondary bonus point, MVC5 comes rigged up with friendly "an error occurred processing your request" error pages instead of hard server error messages. I can't for the life of me find how to disable this so I can get some kind of idea of what has failed!

Comment: Have you created new API keys for your webserver? When you use Google OAuth, the auth keys you get are only valid for the url you register with, which is your local http://localhost/MyAppName/Login url. For webserver you need another pair and update it accordingly

Comment: I have indeed - I can see that a request is being logged in my google api monitoring, but it is obviously not validating somewhere along the line. I cant see what the error is as I get presented with the fluffy error message.

Comment: The wait seems to be happening on this line of code in my ExternalLoginCallBack:                var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);